# Что нужно делать в файле config и init?

Tags: php, структуры

Делаю что-то своего движка. Блоговый сайт, так вот в каждой странице нужно подключать файл с переменными, константами и модулями.

- Например, в файле `dir.php`, где я пишу рабочие и системные пути, как константы.
- В файле `config.php` я делаю константы для покдлючения в базе данных
- А в файле `init.php` я подключаю все файлы.

Есть несколько вопросов.

1. Все ли я делаю правильно по структуре?
2. Что можно еще добавить в конфигурационные файлы? Что я забыл?

Comment: Сейчас модно делать немного по другому https://tyapk.ru/blog/post/php-autoload

Comment: А по данному вопросу есть что?